# Newton Iteration Function

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, chaos-theory

So I'm having trouble figuring this problem out so if someone can help me out that'd be great.

Find all the fixed points for the associated Newton iteration function for $$
f(x) = \frac{x}{(x-1)^n}
$$
when $n = 1, 2, 3, .....$ Which are attracting and which are repelling?

Comment: fixed points are $(0,0) ,(2,2)$ ?

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Your first point is correct, but the other contradicts my answer. Also, you shouldn't answer a question with a question.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)={{x} \over {(x-1)^n}}$$
$$f^{'}(x)=\left({{-n} \over {x-1}}+1 \right) \cdot (x-1)^{-n}$$
Implementing Newton's method recurrence...
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-{{f(x)} \over {f^{'}(x)}}$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+{{x_n \cdot (x_n-1)} \over {(n-1) \cdot x_n+1}}$$
A fixed point is defined as a value $v$ such that $x_1=v$
So solve for x...
$$x=x+{{x \cdot (x-1)} \over {(n-1) \cdot x+1}}$$
Clearly, $x=1$, and $x=0$ are the fixed points

It might be enlightening to now investigate the periodic points of the dynamical system. A periodic point of period n is an $x_n=v$, so the solution oscillates between n values. An period "1" solution is just a typical fixed point...

Comment: How would you know which ones are attracting/repelling?

Comment: @MoonDog Take the derivative of the right hand side with respect to x at the points of interest. If it's absolute value is less than one its attractive. If its absolute value is greater than one, it repulsive.

Comment: Very nice analysis. It might be interesting to note that this is unexpected. Typically, we figure that $N(x)=x-f(x)/f'(x)$ has a fixed point at $x_0$ only if $f(x_0)=0$. I guess this example also shows that we can also have a fixed point at $x_0$ if $f'(x_0)=\infty$. Another example would be $\sqrt[3]{x}$.